# Defining a class with functor-ish and non-functor-ish functions

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

I want to define a class `m` that provides an functor-ish operation with
a type signature like this:

mapify :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b

I needed some other non-functor-ish operations as well, though. I would
have liked to write something along the lines of:

```
class MyMap m where
  type Key m
  type Value m
  keys :: m -> [Key m]
  elems :: m -> [Value m]
  mapify :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b -- WON'T WORK!!!
```

I understand why that won't work. The solution I came up with was to split it into two classes, a "normal" one plus one modelled on Functor.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

class MyMap m where
  type Key m
  type Value m
  keys :: m -> [Key m]
  elems :: m -> [Value m]

class MyMapF m where
  mapify :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b

instance MyMap (M.Map k v) where
  type Key (M.Map k v) = k
  type Value (M.Map k v) = v
  keys = M.keys
  elems = M.elems

instance MyMapF (M.Map k) where
  mapify = M.map
```

That works fine, but is there a better way?

---

EDIT: I really like the solution proposed by sabauma. However, when I try to create a function that uses this class, I can't get the type signature to work out.

```
doSomething
  :: (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2) => -- line 22
    (Value m1 -> Value m2) -> m1 -> m2                    -- line 23
doSomething f m = mapify f m                              -- line 24
```

The error I get is:

```
../Amy3.hs:22:6:
    Couldn't match type `b0' with `Value (Container m0 b0)'
      `b0' is untouchable
           inside the constraints (MyMap m1,
                                   MyMap m2,
                                   Container m1 ~ Container m2)
           bound at the type signature for
                      doSomething :: (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2) =>
                                     (Value m1 -> Value m2) -> m1 -> m2
    Expected type: a0 -> b0
      Actual type: Value m1 -> Value m2

../Amy3.hs:24:19:
    Could not deduce (m2 ~ Container m0 b0)
    from the context (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2)
      bound by the type signature for
                 doSomething :: (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2) =>
                                (Value m1 -> Value m2) -> m1 -> m2
      at ../Amy3.hs:(22,6)-(23,38)
      `m2' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             doSomething :: (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2) =>
                            (Value m1 -> Value m2) -> m1 -> m2
           at ../Amy3.hs:22:6
    In the return type of a call of `mapify'
    In the expression: mapify f m
    In an equation for `doSomething': doSomething f m = mapify f m

../Amy3.hs:24:28:
    Could not deduce (m1 ~ Container m0 a0)
    from the context (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2)
      bound by the type signature for
                 doSomething :: (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2) =>
                                (Value m1 -> Value m2) -> m1 -> m2
      at ../Amy3.hs:(22,6)-(23,38)
      `m1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             doSomething :: (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, Container m1 ~ Container m2) =>
                            (Value m1 -> Value m2) -> m1 -> m2
           at ../Amy3.hs:22:6
    In the second argument of `mapify', namely `m'
    In the expression: mapify f m
    In an equation for `doSomething': doSomething f m = mapify f m
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: I wonder if `class Functor m => MyMap m where ...` wouldn't have worked? That way, you can simply reuse the `Functor` part and don't need to worry about `m` vs `m a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to encode the "Container" type using another associated
type.

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

class MyMap m where
  type Key m
  type Value m
  type Container m :: * -> *
  keys :: m -> [Key m]
  elems :: m -> [Value m]
  mapify :: (a -> b) -> Container m a -> Container m b

instance MyMap (M.Map k v) where
  type Key (M.Map k v) = k
  type Value (M.Map k v) = v
  type Container (M.Map k v) = M.Map k
  keys = M.keys
  elems = M.elems
  mapify = M.map
```

The idea being that the `Container` for a `Map` is `Map k`, so you bundle the
`Map` with its associated key type. That way, your `mapify` function lifts
your function into the container. Whether or not is is 'better' is up to you,
I guess, but it does cut down on the number of type classes. You should not
need the `MyMapF` class with your example, since `MyMapF` is the same as the
standard `Functor` typeclass.

Alright, that error can be fixed by modifying the definition of `mapify`
slightly.

```
class MyMap m where
  type Key m
  type Value m
  type Container m :: * -> *
  keys :: m -> [Key m]
  elems :: m -> [Value m]
  -- mapify :: (a -> b) -> Container m a -> Container m b

  -- Make sure the type-checker knows that m2 is just the container of m with
  -- a different value
  mapify :: (MyMap m2, m2 ~ Container m (Value m2)) => (Value m -> Value m2) -> m -> m2


instance MyMap (M.Map k v) where
  type Key (M.Map k v) = k
  type Value (M.Map k v) = v
  type Container (M.Map k v) = M.Map k
  keys = M.keys
  elems = M.elems
  mapify = M.map

doSomething
  :: (MyMap m1, MyMap m2, m2 ~ Container m1 (Value m2)) =>
     (Value m1 -> Value m2) -> m1 -> m2
doSomething f m = mapify f m
```

This will type-check. I think the problem is just that the type-checker needs
a stronger hint that all you are doing is altering the `Value` of the `MyMap`
instance, without changing the underlying container.

Comment: Thank you! It is much better for me, because in the domain I'm working with, all the functions "belong" together. By the way, I can't use 'Functor' because there are several "functor-ish" operations I need to provide, like 'mapValueWithKey'. However, now I'm having a type signature problem (see edit above).

Comment: @mhwombat I had to change up the class definition slightly, but this new version seems to type-check. Perhaps someone else knows a better way to encode this?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is a bit old, but I ran across it looking for something unrelated and had an idea you might like, especially since it seems a bit simpler than the one proposed by sabauma.

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

class MyMap m where
  type Key m
  keys :: m a -> [Key m]
  elems :: m a -> [a]
  mapify :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b

instance MyMap (M.Map k) where
  type Key (M.Map k) = k
  keys = M.keys
  elems = M.elems
  mapify = M.map
```

See also the [keys](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys) package.